# How do I update the values of these Int refs (Haskell)?

Tags: variables, haskell, syntax, reference

I have some variables like so:

```
let y0 = read (input!!0) :: Int
let h = read (input!!1) :: Int
y <- newIORef y0
minY <- newIORef 0 
maxY <- newIORef (h - 1)
```

And later I have

```
y_old <- readIORef y

if (some_string!!0 == 'U') then   
    maxY = (y_old - 1)       --I don't think this is working
else if (some_string!!0 == 'D') then
    minY = (y_old + 1)       --I don't think this is working
```

I am basically reading the references into some local ints and then trying to update the references based on criteria.

I also tried `modifyIORef maxY (y_old - 1)` but this doesn't work either. The compiler is only telling me "parse error" or "syntax error" which is not helpful.

My full code:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering -- DO NOT REMOVE

    -- Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
    -- the standard input according to the problem statement.

    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let w = read (input!!0) :: Int -- width of the building.
    let h = read (input!!1) :: Int -- height of the building.
    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int -- maximum number of turns before game over.
    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let x0 = read (input!!0) :: Int
    let y0 = read (input!!1) :: Int
    x <- newIORef x0
    y <- newIORef y0
    minX <- newIORef 0 
    maxX <- newIORef (w - 1) 
    minY <- newIORef 0 
    maxY <- newIORef (h - 1) 
    loop x0 y0 w h x y minX maxX minY maxY

loop :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IORef Int-> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IO ()
loop x0 y0 w h x y minX maxX minY maxY = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let bombdir = input_line :: String -- the direction of the bombs from batman's current location (U, UR, R, DR, D, DL, L or UL)

    x_old <- readIORef x 
    y_old <- readIORef y

    if (bombdir!!0 == 'U') then
        writeIORef maxY (y_old - 1)
    if (bombdir!!0 == 'D') then
        writeIORef minY (y_old + 1)

    if (bombdir!!(bombdir.length-1) == 'L') then
        writeIORef maxX (x_old - 1)
    if (bombdir!!(bombdir.length-1) == 'R') then
        writeIORef minX (x_old + 1)


    x = (minX + maxX) / 2
    y = (minY + maxY) / 2

    x_out <- readIORef x 
    y_out <- readIORef y


    printf "%d %d" x_out y_out
    loop x0 y0 w h x y minX maxX minY maxY
```

Comment: If you just have two clauses, you just need `if something then something else something` instead of another if. If you've already read the ioref then you probably want to use writeIORef. Furthermore, are you sure you need an IORef? Quite often it can be done a much better way.

Comment: Please give a [MCVE]. If you have parse errors, you're likely not using `do` syntax properly.

Comment: This looks like you want to write *imperative* programs in Haskell (functional language). Although this is of course possible, usually it is a very bad idea to do so. You also do not provide an `else` for the last `if` case. It is also usually an anti-pattern to use `(!!)`, since it is a non-total (and for arbitrary index inefficient) function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I can't give a full MCVE here because it's part of an online game

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're right that I am trying to write imperative style -- it's because I don't know how to write my desired program using non-imperative style. Have literally wasted like 4 days trying to do that with no progress -- so until I can finish the problem / see how other people did it / learn from that, I'm cheesing it with IORefs.

Comment: @user8930358: usually if you want to iterate over something, one uses recursion, usually instead of (chained) `if`-`then`-`else`s, one uses guards.

Comment: @user8930358: In order to help you I think it is better to first specify the problem you are aiming to solve. Right now you are only giving a program. This is basically the XY-problem. Based on your description, there is no way to show how to implement things in a better way, since we do not know what you aim to do.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am trying to beat this challenge using Haskell: https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/shadows-of-the-knight-episode-1 I already have a working algorithm and everything and have completed this challenge in an imperative language or two, but I want to also complete it learning Haskell.

Comment: `modifyIORef maxY (y_old - 1)` is syntactically valid (if not type correct) so if you get errors, you should include those errors and the steps required to  produce them. What you want is something like `if condition then modifyIORef maxY (subtract 1) else return ()` which roughly does the same thing as `if (condition) { maxY = maxY - 1 }` in an imperative language.

Comment: @user2407038 Using that syntax introduced a huge slew of errors so I don't know if that's my issue (couldn't match expected type Int -> Int with actual type Int, possible cause - is applied to too many arguments)

Comment: Sorry that you're having a frustrating experience, but I can only add to the chorus: the reason seems to be that you're working _against_ the language, rather than _with_ it. Haskell is so different from most other programming languages that _just coding something_, without really having learned the basic ideas, is bound to lead to big disappointment. I strongly recommend reading a book first.

Comment: @user2407038 (gaah, can you guys please get some proper nicknames so SO's autocomplete works?) Your suggestion `modifyIORef maxY (subtract 1)` does something different from what the OP wants: `maxY ⟻ (y - 1)`, not `maxY ⟻ (maxY - 1)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've been down that road like 4 times already with no luck. How do I work with the language then to solve a challenge like this? I don't even know what I need to be looking for. The problem constantly gives you inputs in a loop and you have to update your search space until you narrow in on the target.

Comment: @user8930358 that shouldn't require IORefs, just a recursive “loop” where each input causes the function to call itself with modified argument. A better alternative would be to take the entire input from a [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), then you hardly need to worry about control flow at all.

Comment: @leftaroundabout How would I set up such a recursion? I'm not asking you to solve the problem (I've already solved it in other languages and know what to set up), but how I'd carry all these updated variables along in a recursion and output commands based on input. I don't think I can use a conduit since an output is expected after each input is received (I can't receive all the inputs at once and then output stuff).

Comment: Being able to process input piece-by-piece and responding dynamically is what conduits are all about. So, that wouldn't be a problem. Still, I think for learning purpose a manual-recursion approach is better. — We can show you how to do that, but you'd need to narrow it down to some simple, complete, well-specified use scenario, else it's _too broad_ for SO. That would probably something for a new question. Whereas _this_ question could be salvaged if you completed the code so there is on concrete problem we can discuss. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: @leftaroundabout I updated the post with my full code so far. Please note that the logic is sound (i.e. the intended layout of my code solves the problem in terms of  how it's trying to update the x's and y's) but the syntax / use of Haskell is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a bit of good style:

```
    ...
    input_line <- getLine
    let input = words input_line
    let w = read (input!!0) :: Int -- width of the building.
    let h = read (input!!1) :: Int -- height of the building.
```

This works, but it's awkward. You build up a list and give it a name, only to access individual elements, parse them one-by-one and give them new names. Why not just

```
    input_line <- getLine
    let [w,h] = map read (words input_line) :: [Int]
```

In fact, you don't even need `input_line`, nor the signatures (provided you later *use* `w` and `h`, so their types are unambiguous). I.e., the following also does the trick:

```
    [w,h] <- map read . words <$> getLine
```

Likewise,

```
    [x₀,y₀] <- map read . words <$> getLine
```

The real problem with your code in `loop` is that you try to use `if` as a procedural control-flow statement. Haskell *doesn't have control flow*, it only has expressions. Hence Haskell's `if` is actually very different from the `if` statement in imperative languages, it's more like the `? :` operator. One thing you could do is complete these conditionals to

```
    if (bombdir!!0 == 'U')
     then writeIORef maxY (y_old - 1)
     else pure ()
```

...`pure ()` being the no-op in a pseudo-imperative (monadic) `do` block. But there's a standard combinator for this particular construct, [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when). It's actually just a library function, but behaves almost exactly like `if` in imperative languages. With that, you could make it

```
    when (bombdir!!0 == 'U') $ writeIORef maxY (y_old - 1)
```

But I wouldn't recommend it. You're again do awkward list-element accessing. A much nicer way of deciding what to do depending on values of list-elements is directly pattern-matching them with a `case` expression:

```
loop :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
 -> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IORef Int-> IORef Int -> IORef Int -> IO ()
loop x₀ y₀ w h x y minX maxX minY maxY = do

    bombdir <- getLine  -- no need to first name it `input_line`

    x_old <- readIORef x 
    y_old <- readIORef y

    case bomdir of
      ('U':_) -> writeIORef maxY (y_old - 1)
      ('D':_) -> writeIORef minY (y_old + 1)
      _       -> pure ()

    case reverse bombdir of
      ('L':_) -> writeIORef maxX (x_old - 1)
      ('R':_) -> writeIORef minX (x_old + 1)
      _       -> pure ()
```

Then, you attempt to do arithmetic directly on IORefs, instead of on pure values. This is generally eschewed; what you'd actually need to write is

```
    writeIORef x =<< do
        xmin <- readIORef minX
        xmax <- readIORef maxX
        pure $ (xmin + xmax) / 2
```

I think we agree that this looks horrible, but it works. A more concise way of writing it would be

```
    writeIORef x =<< (/2) <$> ((+) <$> readIORef minX <*> readIORef maxX)
```

As I already commented, you fortunately don't need those ugly IORefs at all. Just make “new versions” of your variables to pass in the recursive call:

```
loop :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int-> Int -> Int -> IO ()
loop x₀ y₀ w h x y minX maxX minY maxY = do
    bombdir <- input_line

    let (maxY',minY') = case bombdir of
          ('U':_) -> (y - 1, minY )
          ('D':_) -> (maxY , y + 1)
        (maxX',minX') = case reverse bombdir of
          ('L':_) -> (x - 1, minX )
          ('R':_) -> (maxX , x + 1)

        x' = (minX' + maxX') / 2
        y' = (minY' + maxY') / 2

    printf "%d %d" x' y'
    loop x₀ y₀ w h x' y' minX' maxX' minY' maxY'
```

Comment: This was extraordinarily helpful -- thank you. As an aside the compiler was giving me an error about the pattern matching being nonexhaustive but it worked after I added a case to each `_ -> (maxY, minY)` for example, is this the right practice?

Comment: So the general idea is that we don't change variables -- we recurse / call new functions with modified arguments and that's how we update state?